# Is an input type button the same as a bootstrap button for modals?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is an input type button the same as a bootstrap button for modals?

bootstrap modal button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
```

Input button:

```
<input type="button" id="yes_delete" value="Yes " />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style of each element is described in the bootstrap documentation. The ID you added doesn't make any change, but you can enable Javascript on element ID's better then on class types as it is more efficient.

Incase you didn't get it, the class `btn btn-default` determins how the button is displayed and you can play around with it seen [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options)